# decltype and the scope operator in C++

Tags: c++, scope, c++11, operator-keyword, decltype

I need to obtain the type which was supplied when instantiating a template. Consider the following example:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo
{
  typedef T TUnderlying;
};

static Foo<int> FooInt;

class Bar
{
public:
  auto Automatic() -> decltype(FooInt)::TUnderlying
  {
    return decltype(FooInt)::TUnderlying();
  }
};

int main()
{
  Bar bar;
  auto v = bar.Automatic();
    return 0;
}
```

Problem with this code is using the scope operator together with decltype. Visual C++ 2010 complains like this:

error C2039: 'TUnderlying' : is not a member of '`global namespace''

I gathered some information on the topic on Wikipedia:

While commenting on the formal Committee Draft for C++0x, the Japanese ISO member body noted that "a scope operator(::) cannot be applied to decltype, but it should be. It would be useful in the case to obtain member type(nested-type) from an instance as follows":[16]

```
vector<int> v;
decltype(v)::value_type i = 0; // int i = 0;
```

This, and similar issues were addressed by David Vandevoorde, and voted into the working paper in March 2010.

So I reckon the Visual C++ 2010 does not have this implemented. I came up with this workaround:

```
template <typename T> struct ScopeOperatorWorkaroundWrapper
{
  typedef typename T::TUnderlying TTypedeffedUnderlying;
};

auto Automatic() -> ScopeOperatorWorkaroundWrapper<decltype(FooInt)>::TTypedeffedUnderlying
{
  return ScopeOperatorWorkaroundWrapper<decltype(FooInt)>::TTypedeffedUnderlying();
}
```

Did I miss any solution which is more elegant and less verbose?

Comment: Have you tried `FooInt::TUnderlying` instead of `decltype(FooInt)::TUnderlying`? I don't see what you expect to gain via `decltype` here.

Comment: All you add is `ScopeOperatorWorkaroundWrapper<>`, I don't know how much "less verbose" you could want it. After all, its a workaround.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This transparently replaces the `decltype` keyword with the template based workaround. Once you no longer need to support MSVC2010 you can remove the macro definition without changing any user code:

```
#if _MSC_VER == 1600
#include <utility>
#define decltype(...) \
  std::identity<decltype(__VA_ARGS__)>::type
#endif
```

Which allows this to compile and work on MSVC10:

```
std::vector<int> v;
decltype(v)::value_type i = 0;
```

---

Note that `std::identity` isn't part of the C++ standard, but it's safe to rely on it here as the workaround is limited to a compiler which includes `std::identity` in its standard library implementation.

Comment: Use variadic macros to workaround the comma issue. `#define decltype(...) detail::type_helper<decltype(__VA_ARGS__)>::type`. Note that `decltype(x)` may not be the same as `decltype((x))`, so your `t2` could result in a different type.

Comment: @KennyTM: Thanks, I've incorporated that into the answer.

Comment: I see this solution as the least intrusive and easiest to remove once the compiler implements this feature. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Unfortunately, the version with __VA__ARGS__ does not compile under MSVC (error C2065: '__VA__ARGS__' : undeclared identifier), so I will have to stick with the `#define decltype(exp)` , but that is still fine by me.

Comment: It compiles fine for me. Are you using it exactly as written? The leading and trailing underscores in `__VA__ARGS__` are significant.

Comment: The definition of the workaround you provided (the first code paragraph) compiles fine, but the compiler error appears when I actually try to use it somewhere. Following code does not compile for me under MSVC:  #include <vector>  

namespace detail {  
  template <class T>  
  struct type_helper {  
    typedef T type;  
  };  
}  
  
#define decltype(...) \  
  detail::type_helper<decltype(__VA__ARGS__)>::type  
    
int main()  
{  
  std::vector<int> v;  
  decltype(v)::value_type i = 0;  
 return 0;  
}

Comment: Sorry for the missing code block (and the missing leading and trailing underscores, they got stripped automatically), I can not edit that comment anymore.

Comment: There should only be a single underscore, not a double, between VA and ARGS - `__VA_ARGS__`. I've corrected it in the answer.

Comment: VS2010 has std::identity too - so you could do `#define decltype(...) std::identity<decltype(__VA_ARGS__)>::type` specifically for VS

Comment: @Vidar Hasfjord; Sorry your edit got rejected - you're quite right, <utility> is the correct header.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround looks relatively fine but it’s not extensible and the names are horrible<sup>1</sup>. Why not use `id`?

```
template <typename T>
struct id {
    typedef T type;
};
```

And then:

```
id<decltype(FooInt)>::type::TUnderlying;
```

Untested, but should work.

---

<sup>1</sup> As in, too verbose and even though they describe that it’s a workaround, this may be redundant and not a useful information in most of the situations.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Regarding the names - it was just an example and I admit that the names could be a bit shorter, but I prefer names which capture the reasoning of the problem. Plain "id" would later (when I forget about it) tell me nothing that it was just a temporary hack. I think that it is not necessary with modern auto completion features at hand to make my code hard to understand with cryptic abbreviations.

Comment: @Milan `id` is the correct name for this metafunction (it’s the [identity function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function)), and I think it’s actually already defined somewhere in C++11 precisely to serve as a syntactic workaround in places where a plain type cannot be used. Either way, you *should* use this name since it’s the established name for this concept and it’s generally understood. It’s by no means a “cryptic abbreviation” (which I agree should never be used).

Comment: @Milan But since you mentioned auto completion: the reason to avoid long names is *not* that it takes long to type them (auto-completion helps here, true). But it also makes the code *unreadable*, and concise (brief, yet accurate) names should always be preferred.

Comment: VC++ 2010 comes with `std::identity<>` that does exactly this for exactly this purpose.

Comment: @ildjarn Unfortunately I can’t find it in the C++11 standard draft. But then, the search in Preview sucks so it may be there.

Comment: @Konrad : It was in earlier drafts (e.g. N3000, which VC++ 2010 was based on), but it's not in the final C++11 standard.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can easily pull the type out using a function template helper:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo
{
    typedef T TUnderlying;
};

static Foo<int> FooInt;

template <typename T>
typename Foo<T>::TUnderlying foo_underlying(Foo<T> const &)
{
    return typename Foo<T>::TUnderlying();
}

class Bar
{
public:
//    auto Automatic() -> decltype(FooInt)::Underlying
//    {
//        return decltype(FooInt)::Underlying;
//    }
    auto Automatic() -> decltype(foo_underlying(FooInt))
    {
        return foo_underlying(FooInt);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bar bar;
    auto v = bar.Automatic();
}
```