# How to get element type from STL container instance?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, decltype

I know about value_type, key_type...  but they operate on types, not on instances. 
I tried 
stuff like :

```
std::set<uint64_t> mySet;   

decltype (mySet)::value_type pos;
```

But it doesnt work.

EDIT: I use VS 2010.

EDIT2: the prupose of this code was to get a type to give it to boost::lexical_cast<>
is there a workaround that enables that ?
I want something like this:

```
   mySet.insert(boost::lexical_cast<decltype(mySet)::value_type>(*it));
  // it is a iterator in vector of strings
```

EDIT3 : this works:

```
mySet.insert(boost::lexical_cast<decltype(mySet)::value_type>(*it));
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: `decltype (mySet)::value_type pos;` is correct. There's a bug in the 2010 Microsoft compiler that doesn't allow decltype to be followed by a `::` (see question linked as duplicate)

Comment: possible duplicate of [decltype and the scope operator in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291336/decltype-and-the-scope-operator-in-c)

Comment: Given that you're apparently dealing with a buggy compiler, one possible workaround would be something like: `auto pos = *(mySet.begin());`

Comment: If what you are trying to do actually works, it seems to me that your parentheses are in the wrong place. Try `(decltype mySet)::value_type pos;` and let us know what happens. (DISCLAIMER: I have never used `decltype` in my own C++ programs, so this is just a guess.)

Comment: A workaround: `typedef decltype(mySet) T; T::value_type pos;`

Comment: Don't use `uint64_t` unless you have an absolute requirement that the size be **exactly** 64 bits. Use `uint_least64_t` instead; it will exist on systems that don't have a 64-bit integer type but do have something larger.

Comment: @Pete: I do wonder whether the folks over on the C standard committee were sponsored by keyboard manufacturers when they defined `<stdint>`. In theory `uint_least64_t` should be used more than `uint64_t`, but it never will be.

Comment: @SteveJessop - I hope it will be, since `uint64_t` is not required to exist. But I agree: the names of the most useful ones are longwinded.

Comment: @JoeGauterin tnx, that works. :D

Comment: There's also an interesting (to me) kink in the standard, that `int64_t` if it exists is guaranteed 2's complement, whereas `int_least64_t` isn't. So there's an extra consideration when selecting your signed type, that doesn't apply to unsigned.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`decltype (mySet)::value_type` is correct. Make sure you have C++11 mode enabled in your compiler. If you have, then it's a compiler bug.

A possible workaround involves using the identity metafunction:

```
template <typename T>
struct identity { typedef T type; };

identity<decltype(mySet)>::type::value_type pos;
```

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl VS2010 doesn't let you use scope resolution on `decltype`, but here's a slightly evil way that makes VS2010's `decltype` correct: `#define decltype(...) std::identity<decltype(__VA_ARGS__)>::type`

Answer (score 8):

I'd do it the other way around:

```
typedef std::set<uint_least64_t> set_type;
set_type mySet;
set_type::value_type pos;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of print method that prints elements of a priority queue:

```
template<typename T> void print_queue(T& queue) {
    while (!queue.empty()) {
        std::cout << queue.top() << " ";
        queue.pop();
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The problem is, that after printing of all elements the queue is empty.
To restore the queue to original state we add vector container. The type
of queue elements is deduced from the queue:

```
template<typename T> void print_queue(T& queue) {
    std::vector<T::value_type> vec;
    while (!queue.empty()) {
        std::cout << queue.top() << " ";
        vec.push_back(queue.top());
        queue.pop();
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    for (auto & v : vec) {
        queue.push(v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Combination with the other answers:

```cpp
template<typename TVariant, typename Tfind>
struct is_variant_of {
    template<typename T1, typename T2> struct var_unfold : public std::false_type {};
    template<typename T1, typename... Tlist> struct var_unfold<T1, std::variant<Tlist...>> 
    { constexpr static bool value = (std::is_same_v<T1, Tlist> || ...); };

    constexpr static bool value = var_unfold<Tfind, TVariant>::value;
};

main() {
    using TV = std::variant<int, double>;
    static_assert(is_variant_of<TV, int>::value);
}
```

- `template struct var_unfold{}` to match `std::variant<Ts...>` by partial specialization
- Using `std::is_same_v` with c++17 fold expression