# How to find out template parameter Type that STL container holds

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

For example `vector<int> coll`, holds `int` type objects. What if I don't know that `coll` is holds `int`(but I know it is vector), how would I go about finding type information ?

Comment: Why do you need to know exactly? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get element type from STL container instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391814/how-to-get-element-type-from-stl-container-instance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab the information from the object's `value_type`:

```
using value_type = decltype(coll)::value_type;

static_assert(std::is_same<value_type, int>::value, "Type is not an int");
```

<sub>Use of the `using` alias and `static_assert` is available in C++11+</sub>

Though this can always be determined by using templates (which is more common):

```
template <class T>
void f(std::vector<T>& v); // use T as the type
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the first method works only in C++11, while the second one also in C++98/03 (which doesn't have the `decltype` keyword).

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yep, `decltype` is new C++11 feature

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yup. :)