# How to circumvent Intel C++ compiler's issue with `decltype` and inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, icc, decltype

I was very surprised today to discover that *Intel's icpc* (version 14.0.2, using `std=c++0x`) fails to compile the following snippet.

---

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace traits_tests {
  template<typename>
  struct sfinae_true : std::true_type {};

  template<typename T>
  static auto value_type(int) -> sfinae_true<typename T::value_type>;
  template<typename T>
  static auto value_type(void*) -> std::false_type;
}

template<typename C>
struct has_value_type
  : decltype(traits_tests::value_type<C>(0)) {};
```

complaining about the last line:

```
inc/traits.h(258): error: expected an identifier
    : decltype(traits_tests::value_type<C>(0)) {};
      ^
```

---

The code works fine with `clang` and `gcc`.

I don't really fancy a complete re-write to make it work with flawed compilers (why is that always the commercial compilers are flawed?).

- Is there a simpler way, than a completely different SFINAE pattern, to make it work with `icc`?

---

<sup>**EDIT**: Yes, I know that `icc` supports `decltype` since some time. But in the particular context above, `icc` fails to support it. Also note that using `std=c++11` instead of `std=c++0x` makes no difference.</sup>

Comment: It's not always the commercial compilers that are flawed, it's just that people are writing their code on the free compilers *first*, working around *their* issues as they go. ;-) I'm sure users of the Comeau compiler will have had choice words for GCC once they found it didn't support `export`. ;-)

Comment: [According to their compliance page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler), `decltype` has been supported since v12, so I find this odd.

Comment: Could be a missing `template` keyword - see [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/488779) - i.e. try `decltype(template traits_tests::value_type<C>(0)) {};`.

Comment: @DevSolar to be fair IIRC `export` was only partially implemented by Comeau alone, and was left for dead as a feature by the Committee because it just didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a template based workaround - any of the standard types that take a template type argument and expose it as a `typedef`, then wrap that in a macro that's only defined for ICC e.g.

```
#ifdef __INTEL_COMPILER
#include <utility>
#define decltype(...) \
  std::pair<decltype(__VA_ARGS__), int>::first_type
#endif
```

Which allows your example to compile without changes.

Once the bug is fixed in all versions of ICC you're using you can remove the macro definition without changing any other code.

(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9291674/59379) to a similar MSVC issue)

Comment: I actually combined this with the answer by Filip.

Comment: @Walter **Note**: the above "fix" violates `[macro.names]p2`, and renders the program ill-formed.

Comment: A certain level of pragmatism is required here. As shown by this question, the compiler itself doesn't correctly implement the standard you've quoted, and I think stepping outside the standard to correct the compiler's behaviour in this case is a reasonable compromise.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp Yes, but my well-formed program was rejected. I could, of course, follow your suggestion, but that meant to edit every occurence of `decltype` in such circumstances to render a well-formed code overly complex.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the question, and comments, `decltype` has been supported in `icc`for some time now; the problem is that it's not usable in every context because of a nasty bug in the compiler.

---

More specifically it cannot be used directly when specifying the base of a class, which requires us to write a workaround..

If we can't use it *directly*, let's use it *indirectly* (through an *alias template*)!

---

**EXAMPLE WORKAROUND**

```
template<class T>
using identity_hack = T;

template<typename C>
struct has_value_type
  : identity_hack<decltype (traits_tests::value_type<C> (0))>
{ }
```

<sup>**Note:** There are many variations to the above, one could for example use `std::enable_if<true, decltype (...)>::type` as an alternative if one doesn't want to declare something of their own.</sup>