# QHash of QPair iteration

Tags: c++, qhash

```
QHash<QPair<QString N_id, QString A_id>, QString name> info
```

I have this QHash , and i have the values of N_id and name for a particular index, how can i obtain the value of corresponding A_id. I am trying to use STL-style iterator. I can change QHash to QMap if needed but I cannot use:

```
QHash<QPair<QString N_id, QString name>, QString A_id>
```

Edit: N_id and A_id together forms a unique key in my case.

Comment: I think you should change the data structure. maybe you should create a struct which contains N_id,name,A_id and create a map of that struct.

Comment: That would indeed make the question much more readable and more easily understandable.

Comment: @iksemyonov I reverted it. Apply modifications if you think they are appropriate now.

Comment: @ItayGrudev thanks a lot! I appear to be blocked out of editing for some reason (possibly a reject). See my thoughts in the answer below, anyway.

Comment: why not use the latter form `QHash<QPair<QString N_id, QString name>, QString A_id>` if "N_id and name together forms a unique key"?

Comment: N_id and A_id together forms a unique key, i typed name by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I think the major problem here is that `QHash`, being a hash table, looks up the values by hashing the keys. Hence, it needs to complete key to be able to look up a value; a "partial" key won't suffice - there's going to be no concrete object to hash then. A similar problem arises with a map: to navigate the BST, you need the complete object in order to make comparisons and left / right decisions. Thus, short of going back to the drawing board and revising your approach, I'd say, maintain a backwards map, be it a `QHash` or a `QMap`, with the mapping `name` -> `pair(n_id, a_id)`. The downside is that you're going to have to keep the two in sync.

However, with the existing data structure, I'd perform a query like this:

```
#include <algorithm>

QHash<QPair<QString, QString>, QString> info;
QString a_n_id {/*...*/}; // the target N_id
QString a_name {/*...*/}; // the target name
/* ... */
const auto keyList = info.keys(a_name); // QList<QPair<QString, QString> >
std::find_if(keyList.begin(), keyList.end(),
             [&](decltype(info)::key_type& key) { return key.first == a_n_id; });
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291336/decltype-and-the-scope-operator-in-c) in case `decltype(info)::value_type` refuses to build on Microsoft VS.

This is of course going to be linear, since, as I've already said, a hash needs the complete object to be able to perform a lookup, hence we can't use the logarithmic complexity lookup in this case.