# Type Association Without decltype

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, typedef, decltype, typename

So I'm stuck compiling a project in [visual-studio-2010](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2010) and It seems `decltype` isn't implemented.

For example:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo {
    typedef pair<T, T> PointType;
private:
    PointType point;
};
```

When I try to define a variable like this:

```
foo<int> myFoo;
decltype(myFoo)::PointType myBar;
```

I get the error:

> error C2039: `PointType` : is not a member of '`global namespace''

I want to associate `myBar`'s type with `myFoo`'s type. Is there another way to do this, or am I out of luck on [visual-studio-2010](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2010)?

Comment: I don't have VS 2010 to test, but don't you want `decltype(myFoo) myBar` to associate it with `foo` or `decltype(myFoo.point) myBar` to associate it with `PointType`?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537655(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @zzxyz That's actually a really good suggestion, but only because I didn't fully develop my toy example, in my code `point` is private. So I can't use the member variable type.

Comment: Hmmm:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291336/decltype-and-the-scope-operator-in-c?rq=1

Comment: @zzxyz Well that's a great link. I'm not happy with that answer, but it looks like that's the best I can do for now.

Comment: Yeah, looks....not ideal :)

Comment: How about using straight approach? `typedef foo<int> MyFoo; MyFoo my_foo; MyFoo::PointType my_bar;`

Comment: @VTT So my code works fine with a C++11 compliant compiler: https://ideone.com/scGOvP but `myFoo::PointType myBar` isn't legal anywhere: https://ideone.com/hhd21B

Comment: Yes, so you can utilize my suggestion to [make it work](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mX4rMa3cSV8KcAmV).

Comment: @VTT I do like that better than the other linked question, it may in fact be our best bet :(